# Python XML - Iterate through elements, and if attribute condition is met, append that element with all its children to the list

Tags: python, xml, list, nested, children

I have script that is supposed to filter out some elements out of XML file. I did it like this because I exactly knew what is depth of element, how many children there are...
But can you please give me an example of how this can be done without knowing the depth of nest?

Code looks like this:

```py
def Filter_Modules(folder_name, corresponding_list):
    for element in delta_root.iter('folder'):
      if element.attrib.get('name') == str(folder_name):
        corresponding_list.append(element)
        for child in element:
          corresponding_list.append(child)
          for ch in child:
            corresponding_list.append(ch)
            for c in ch:
              corresponding_list.append(c)
```

All suggestions are welcome..

Comment: share the xml (make sure it is valid!) and explain what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to put in `corresponding_list` all
descendant elements of the `folder` element of which the `name`
attribute equals some string.

Then a good solution for that is to use a *recursive* function.  (In
general, recursivity is a good approach to handle data structures like
trees, graphs, ...).

The recursive function `add_sub_tree` appends and `element` to
`corresponding_list` and then recursively calls itself on all its
children.  Children will also be appended to `corresponding_list` and
the function will recursively call itself to append all grand-children
and so on.

```py
def Filter_Modules(folder_name, corresponding_list):
    def add_sub_tree(element):
        corresponding_list.append(element)
        for child in element:
            add_sub_tree(child)
        
    for element in delta_root.iter('folder'):
        if element.attrib.get('name') == str(folder_name):
            add_sub_tree(element)
```